# Best way to remove duplicated grouped data - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I have two tables -> Order and OrderLine.  Order contains header information and is the 1 side of the one to many relationship.  OrderLine contains the lines that make up an order and is the many side.

Lets say I have 3 orders, each with their own Ids, but the orderline data for each is identical, I consider that to be duplication, but only if all of the records in the group are identical.

I have tried using CheckSum_Agg for this, but it yields a large number of false positives resulting in records being deleted that are not exact duplicates.

Trying to avoid a nasty, laborious nested cursor.

Any ideas?

Post Edit:
--An example of a false positive being returned by CheckSum_Agg...

```
Create Table #OrderLine(OrderId Int,ProductTypeId Int,ProductId Int);
Insert Into #OrderLine(OrderId,ProductTypeId,ProductId)
Values(1,1,5),(1,2,6),(2,1,6),(2,2,5)

Select CHECKSUM_Agg(ProductTypeId),CHECKSUM_Agg(ProductId)
From #OrderLine
Group By OrderId

Drop Table #OrderLine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CheckSum_Agg is a good start. You're probably only doing CheckSum_Agg on one column. If you do one CheckSum_Agg for each column that you're interested in, you would be able to find all your duplicates. Probably the only columns you're not interested in applying CheckSum_Agg are OrderLine.id and OrderLine.OrderId.

Here's a query that will check row by row if the two orders are the same:

```
with o as (
  select distinct orderid from orderline)
, ol as (select * from orderline)
select o1.orderid as o1, o2.orderid as o2
from o o1, o o2 
where o1.orderid <> o2.orderid and
0= (select count(*) 
          from (select * from ol where ol.orderid = o1.orderid) ol1 
          full outer join 
            (select * from ol where ol.orderid = o2.orderid) ol2 
            on ol1.producttypeid = ol2.producttypeid
            and ol1.productid = ol2.productid
          where (ol2.orderid is null or ol1.orderid is null))
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/359e5/8

The idea here is to get all pairs (o1, o2) of orders and match up the orderlines ol1 of o1 to the orderlines ol2 of o2 to see if they are matching. If they all match, then they're duplicates of each other.

This is probably a very expensive operation. I would recommend an index that has all of the columns in the full outer join critera to speed this up.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Actually I have tried that and it doesn't work.

Here's a simplified example of a scenario where it gives false positives:

Order Lines Table Includes these two rows

First order has two records:
Order Type Id: 1, Product Id: 5
Order Type Id: 2, Product Id: 6

Second order has two records:
Order Type Id: 1, Product Id: 6
Order Type Id: 2, Product Id: 5

Checksum_Agg says these are identical and they are not.

Comment: Create Table #OrderLine(OrderId Int,ProductTypeId Int,ProductId Int);<BR />
Insert Into #OrderLine(OrderId,ProductTypeId,ProductId)<BR />
Values(1,1,5),(1,2,6),(2,1,6),(2,2,5)<BR />
<BR />
Select CHECKSUM_Agg(ProductTypeId),CHECKSUM_Agg(ProductId)<BR />
From #OrderLine<BR />
Group By OrderId<BR />
<BR />
Drop Table #OrderLine<BR />

Comment: I've added the code snippet to the main question since I can't seem to do any formatting in the comments.

Comment: @Jimbo I created a fiddle from your example (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c54c0/1). I see what you mean now. The checksum didn't seem to catch your differences. I suggest full outer joining groups together to search for differences.

Comment: @jimbo I've updated answer with a different query that will compare the orders row by row to see if they are the same.

Comment: Works brilliantly.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow dupes in your table I recommend creating a surrogate key to allow easy removal.  Better not to allow them in the first place, with a unique constraint.  But try this to clean up.

```
Create Table #OrderLine(Pk INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, OrderId Int,ProductTypeId Int,ProductId Int);
Insert Into #OrderLine(OrderId,ProductTypeId,ProductId)
Values(1,1,5),(1,2,6),(2,1,6),(2,2,5),(1,1,5), (1,1,5)

--check
SELECT * FROM #OrderLine

--any dupes?
SELECT * FROM #OrderLine WHERE Pk NOT IN (
    Select Min(Pk)
    From #OrderLine
    Group By OrderId,ProductTypeId,ProductId
)

--delete the dupes
DELETE FROM #OrderLine WHERE Pk NOT IN (
    Select Min(Pk)
    From #OrderLine
    Group By OrderId,ProductTypeId,ProductId
)

--check
SELECT * FROM #OrderLine

Drop Table #OrderLine
```